# "have a refined bearing" OR "have a bearing with/of refinement"

Tags: phrases, word-usage, collocation

thank you for answering my question.

I was learning "bearing" with all its collocations, and there I learned that it can be used to describe the way in which someone move/stand/behave.

I recalled that "refinement" can also be used to express one's way of behaving. So I was thinking whether if it's possible to form a phrase from them. Do you have a suggestion?

Thank you for your time again.

Comment: I would probably say "smooth and well-lubricated".  Of course, I'd be talking about a bicycle bearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**bearing**   [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/16571?rskey=EI1Xk8&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> the carrying of oneself (with reference to the manner); carriage,
>   deportment; behaviour, demeanour.

As in:

> 1873   W. Black Princess of Thule vi. 86   She could not fail to see
>   the courtesy of his **bearing** towards women.

and

She was an imposing attorney with a **refined bearing**.

and

She was an imposing attorney with a **bearing of refinement**.

Either of your suggestions are correct and grammatical.